# How to extract private key ,created using Strong Name tool (sn.exe)?

Tags: .net, key, strongname

Sn.exe provides options for key management, signature generation, and signature verification.

For creating public and private key pair following command is used-

```
sn -k keyPair.snk
```

public key could be extracted using-

```
sn -p keyPair.snk publicKey.snk
```

I want to see the corresponding **private key** of the pair generated,

How can i do that ?

Comment: Please tag your question with appropriate technologies like .Net, C#, VB or C++, for better response.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412011/extracting-private-key-from-a-strong-name-file , Plz refer to this link too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: There is enough information in the private key to trivially re-derive the public key information. As such, there's no point in extracting just the private key.

Comment: If i need to decrypt data encrypted by my public key,i'll need private key to do the same.What will b the process to do it?-Damien

Answer (score 0):

The **SN.exe** utility doesn't offer any way to display the private key. The name itself says that it is a private key. Every public key is unique to its corresponding pair of private key. Had it been possible to know the private key via any tool then any one can infringe the content of your .NET assembly. In that case, the entire motive of digital signing/signature which saves the content of your assembly from malicious tempering would get lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the private key indirectly, by using the -o flag, which (according to MS Docs) prints out the public and private part of the key.

The public part of the key can be recognised within its printout, by using the output of the -p flag.